# Magento 2 - Share customers but not cart between multiple websites or stores

Tags: magento2.2, cart, customer, multistore, quote

We have a Magento 2.2.8 multi-store setup with 3 websites.

One has 2 stores which allows us to share customers between them. However I don't want to share carts between the stores (different products / attribute set).

I'm open to having each store as a separate website (it's easier for product management) but then we lose the ability to share customers as these cannot be shared with global scope.

Therefore, is there an easy way to
1) share customers between selected websites (preferred option, share between 2 websites out of 4)
2) have a separate cart/quote per store

I've looked at the customers module where account scope is set, but trying to limit via IDs doesn't seem to work. Likewise in the quote module while an array of store IDs is passed to load a quote, the loadWithoutStoreIds seems to be called and even hard coding an id to test doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go website route.  Could have something on cron which syncs customers between shared website. This is the least amount of change required.

If you dont want to do this the only other thing I can think to do is set a different root category for the stores you don't want to see each others basket.  Then under the different store scopes start setting different visibility and / or status.

That will stop you adding to cart. That should stop products showing. Not 100% on products already in cart though.

Different domain cookies should force a login when switching between sites if they are on different domains. Therefore entirely possible to utilise a customer login event or account login controller. Could add code to remove unavailable products. This could be attribute based or based on visibility/status.

This is fairly unique requirements so I doubt you will find extension which does the job.

Comment: Thank you - you've solidified my thoughts, but appreciate it's a difficult problem to solve

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found a solution but if you didn't you can check this ready solution
http://www.anowave.com/marketplace/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-disable-cart-and-quote-sharing-between-stores/